# Button not reacting to OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm making a program where a menu has four buttons, and one of these buttons goes to another menu with buttons. The buttons on the first screen work fine, but on the second screen, the buttons don't do anything when pressed. I programmed them the same and I can't figure out why the buttons don't work. Nothing comes up on `LogCat` or Console when I press them.

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/orangebackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="System"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/softwarewords"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Software"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hardwarewords"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Hardware"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logswords"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/system2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Logs"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/system1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hardwarewords"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/box" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/system3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/system1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/system1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/softwarewords"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/system2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/system3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/system3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/system3"
            android:background="@drawable/systemlog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Where Buttons are declared**

```
package com.example.tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class menuforsystem extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.systemmenu);

    Button sys1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.system1);
    Button sys2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.system2);
    Button sys3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.system3);

    sys2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.tutorial.LogsText"));
        }

    });

    sys1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.tutorial.HARDWARETEXT"));
        }

    });

    sys3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.tutorial.SOFTWARETEXT"));
        }

    });
}

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tutorial"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/background1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".main"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >  
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".menu"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.tutorial.MENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".SystemMenu"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.tutorial.SYSTEMMENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".TutorialTwo"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.tutorial.TUTORIALTWO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".TutorialThree"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.tutorial.TUTORIALTHREE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".TutorialFour"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.tutorial.TUTORIALFOUR" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
                android:name=".LogsText"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.tutorial.LogsText" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
                android:name=".HardwareText"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.tutorial.HARDWARETEXT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".SoftwareText"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.tutorial.SOFTWARETEXT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Which one is the `second screen` as you said?

Comment: Try this `startActivity(new Intent(this, LogsText.class));` for `sys2` click event and revert.

Comment: the XML file is the second screen

Comment: @Ullas you can't use `this` there. It would need to be `ActivityName.this` but `v.getContext()` would be better.

Comment: I replaced    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.tutorial.LogsText"));  with the startActivity(new Intent(this, LogsText.class));, and I got an error saying "The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<LogsText>) is undefined". What do you mean by click event and revert?(sorry, I'm new at this)

Comment: @user3795146 read my previous comment about **not** using `this`

Comment: where can I find the Activity Name?

Comment: When I press the buttons, this came up on Logcat. It only came up once, and after I pressed all the buttons many times.  [ViewRootImpl] action cancel 1(atmel) What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

`menuforsystem` activity class is not there in manifest, How can you launch this activity. Probably you are in wrong class, please check.

And one more please dont start Your Class names in small case.

Comment: I added <activity
             android:name=".menuforsystem"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.tutorial.MENUFORSYSTEM" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> to the manifest but it didn't change anything